# Nodemailer got error: 'ECONNRESET' Code:'ESOCKET'

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, nodemailer

I tried to send mail using Nodemailer by using my mail server. It work fine in localhost:8000 buy when I deploy my project to production mode It's  got error: 'ECONNRESET'
 fyi: I use express for the backend and deploy this project on window server 2012

**This is an error**

> error cannot sendmail: Error: read ECONNRESET
>       at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27) {
>     errno: 'ECONNRESET',
>     code: 'ESOCKET',
>     syscall: 'read',
>     command: 'CONN'

**Here is the code**

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'mailserver',
    port: port,
    tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  },
}
)
function Emailsender(email, link) {
let mailOption = {
    from: 'xxxxxxxx@company.org',
    to: `${email}`,
    subject: 'News',
    text: link
}
transporter.sendMail(mailOption, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error cannot sendmail:', err)
    }
    else {
        console.log('Email has been send')
    }
})
}
```

Comment: Where is your production build deployed in cloud ?

Comment: on the company computer server

Comment: U might want to check port firewall access? Is the port opened for access I mean the smtp port

Comment: just check it. it return with status 220. I think firewall is not a problem here

Comment: This is a general connectivity issue and cannot be reproduced with this code.