# Marklogic node js client api not connecting to database

Tags: node.js, marklogic

I am trying to load some documents in my "Documents" database, but am getting this error on running node load.js(filename):

> Error: read ECONNRESET
>       at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27) {
>     errno: -4077,
>     code: 'ECONNRESET',
>     syscall: 'read'
>   }

`load.js`

```
  // Load documents into the database.

const marklogic = require('marklogic');
const my = require('./my-connection.js');
const db = marklogic.createDatabaseClient(my.connInfo);

// Document descriptors to pass to write(). 
const documents = [
  { uri: '/gs/aardvark.json',
    content: {
      name: 'aardvark',
      kind: 'mammal',
      desc: 'The aardvark is a medium-sized burrowing, nocturnal mammal.'
    }
  },
  { uri: '/gs/bluebird.json',
    content: {
      name: 'bluebird',
      kind: 'bird', 
      desc: 'The bluebird is a medium-sized, mostly insectivorous bird.'
    }
  },
  { uri: '/gs/cobra.json',
    content: {
      name: 'cobra',
      kind: 'mammal',
      desc: 'The cobra is a venomous, hooded snake of the family Elapidae.'
    }
  },
];

// Load the example documents into the database
db.documents.write(documents).result( 
  function(response) {
    console.log('Loaded the following documents:');
    response.documents.forEach( function(document) {
      console.log('  ' + document.uri);
    });
  }, 
  function(error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
  }
);
```

`my-connection.js`

```
module.exports = {
  connInfo: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8000,
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password'
  }
};
```

Comment: Others having similar issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59297141/nodemailer-got-error-econnreset-codeesocket

Comment: As Mads suggests, things to check include whether the client can reach the MarkLogic server as well as whether the client is connecting to the port for a REST API server on the MarkLogic server.

Comment: still the issue persists!!

Comment: pasted the code, please let me know  what wrong I am doing?

Comment: Try to see if this REST API server on port 8000 is available. Best way to do this is with a REST API client such as Postman or run a curl command, similar to this:

curl --anyauth --user user:password -X PUT -d@'./two.json' \
  -H "Content-type: application/json" \
  'http://localhost:8000/LATEST/documents?uri=/json/two.json' where two.json is a file you have locally with a simple json content.

Comment: I tried from `Post man` and was able to insert the document, the doc '/json/two.json' is there in the `Documents` database

Comment: Not sure if you are able to resolve. I faced the similar issue today. Most probably, your issue is occuring because your app server is running on HTTPS and you are trying to connect it without SSL in node js code. if anybody knows how to connect node js to marklogic using SSL, please share. Thanks.